# Writing asynchronously to a text file using async.mapLimit

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I'm trying to write numbers between 1 and 100 (order isn't important) to my text file, but only 99 is added.

What's wrong here?

```
app.get('/async', function(req, res) {
  // I create my array here.
  var arr = [];
  for (a = 0; a <= 100; a++) {
    arr.push(a);
  }

  // Here's my async.mapLimit function.
  async.mapLimit(arr, 20, function(arr1, callback) {
    console.log("yes");
    fs.writeFile("ehe.txt", arr1 + "\n", function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
    callback();
  });
});
```

Comment: You should append to the file instead of overwriting it.

Comment: You are explicitly adding numbers where `a < 100`, why do you expect 100 to be added?

Comment: @Paulpro is right, I should have used fs.appendFile. Problem solved now. anderas, my bad. I corrected it to <=

Comment: You'll also probably want to change your loop to be from `1` to `100` instead of `0` to `99`, and use `fs.truncate` to empty the file before you start appending to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using fs.writeFile instead of fs.appendFile and that was causing the overwrite. Changing writeFile to apendFile solved the issue, my bad.